# Dynamic about us page

Tags: 8

I'm fairly new to Drupal and have this task to create an about us page. Now every customer has two certain co-workers assigned to him. This information is stored in the database. I want to show the two co-workers depending on the customer that is signed in. Someone said that I need to create a custom content type, but i couldn't find anything about it online. What would be the best approach to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use Views with a contextual filter based on the logged in user and a relationship from the user to the coworkers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really helped me a lot :)